# Is it possible to pass httprequest parameter from one view function to another in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass Httprequest parameter from one view function to another in Django but it doesn't seem working is it valid to pass the request parameter from one view to another?

```
def view1(request):
    result = view2(request)
    return HttpResponse(result)

def view2(request):
    html = []
    values = request.POST.items()
    for k, v in values:
        html.append('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>' % (k,v))
    return (html)
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Are you getting `POST` request? Or its `GET`?

Comment: I'm sending POST request.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem working" mean?  What happens?  What doesn't happen that you expect to happen?

Comment: If I am trying to print html in view2 it is printing empty [].But When I call view2 from url html is printing the values.so why is it?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. And there is no need to assigning it to a variable. Just use:

```
return view2(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not returning appropriate string for the response. You can update your view as

```
def view1(request):
    result = view2(request)
    return HttpResponse(''.join(result))
```